# Aurelia, what is the purpose and benefit of @customElement

Tags: aurelia

I'm wondering what is exactly the purpose of having @customElement('some-element') decorator and what is the benefit? 
Usually when I want to use 'some-element' I add it in the template like this:

```
   require(from='./some-element')
```

Is it only that we can check if custom attribute is attached to that element and that element is with permanent naming convention?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@customElement(elementName)` decorator explicitly sets the name for the custom element that Aurelia will recognise in the DOM

If you do not specify the element name, Aurelia will use a convention to compute the element's name. The convention hyphenates (kebab cases) the *export name*.

e.g. using conventions

```
export class MyElement { } // the export name is "MyElement"
```

in the DOM:

```
<my-element>
```

**vs**

```
@customElement('hello-world')
export class MyElement {}
```

in the DOM:

```
<hello-world>
```

There are a couple of advantages of having this explicit naming - one of which is that you refactor your class name in code without having to update all the usages of that custom element in your application. Another is when you are creating plugins and want to make sure that the end user can't break your custom element by changing Aurelia's conventions. By being explicit, this can't happen.

The actual name of the *file* used to house the type is not relevant and is just used for your module loader to find/load the file contents.